# Prevarieties s.t. every map to the projective line has a closed image

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a prevariety s.t. every morphism of prevarieties $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ has a closed image. Let $Y$ be an affine variety. I need to show that every map $X \to Y$ is constant.

Any hints, please?

Comment: What definition of "prevariety" are you using? In particular, is $X$ required to be irreducible?

Comment: Hints: embed $Y$ in some $\mathbb A^n$, compose with a projection to $\mathbb A^1$ and again with an immersion $\mathbb A^1\to\mathbb P^1$. As said @Brad, you need to suppose $X$ is irreducible. Note that the term "prevariety" is really outdated.

Comment: @Cantlog Using these compositions we get a map $X \to Y \to \mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$. My definition of a prevariety is a connected space which can be covered by a finite number of affine varieties. So, in particular, it is irreducible. Since the image of an irreducible space under a continuous map is irreducible, the image of $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$, and so in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is open or a single point. Hence $X \to Y$ must be constant. Is this right?